# How to assign xml content to a string explicitly

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, assign

Do you know how I can explicitlyt assign xml content to a string ? 
Example :

```
string myXml = "
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"
```

I want to do this but with a quite bigger file.I need it because I want to use it in my Unit testing but it shows lots of errors when I am trying to paste the content between the quotes.

Answer (score 21):

You need to [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (string which starts with `@` symbol) with escaped quotes (i.e. use double `""` instead of single `"`):

```
        string myXml = @"
<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
";
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
string myXml = @"
    <?xml version=""1.0""?>
    <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    ";
```

Or just store the XML in a file and load it into the variable at runtime using [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx):

```
string myXml = File.ReadAllText("test.xml");
```

Comment: I've been thinking about that option with the file storing.I was wondering if it is a bad practice to keep xml files in my solution?I was wondering of storing it there somewhere so I can read it right the way.

Comment: I believe that storing XML in your code is the _least good_ practice from all the options you have :)

Comment: Why is it a bad practice? It is faster to keep it in a variable. I have to potentially read from the file 20 times in a second. Reading from the file is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with `C# 11`, you can use raw string literals to more easily create strings that are multi-line by using 3 or more double quotes to wrap your string.

For eg:

```cs
string myXml = """
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <note>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    """;
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#raw-string-literals